# How to add roles claim in access_token , currently it is coming in id_token?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am following Authentication code flow with PKCE and my Identity provider is Azure Active directory.
I have created a App , "client-app" from App Registrations. In the manifest I have added appRoles like the following.

```
"appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "User"
      ],
      "displayName": "StoreGroupManager",
      "id": "47fbb575-859a-4941-89c9-0f7a6c30beac",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Consumer apps have access to the consumer data.",
      "value": "StoreGroupManager"
    }
  ]
```

I am assigning this role StoreGroupManager to Users. Now when I follow Authorization code flow with PKCE and obtain the id_token , refresh token and access_token. I can see that the id_token has a claim **roles** but not the access_token.
I need to have roles claim claim in the access_token. Can this be possible?
The following is the **decoded id_token**.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Roles will be in the access token if the app registration for the API that the access token is for defines those roles and they are assigned to the user.
So if you use the same app registration for the client and API, they should be there.
But if you have separate app registrations for the client and API, you will need to define the role in both apps and assign the user to it on both of them as well.

Comment: I have 2 apps registered one for client and another for API. So previously I created roles in the client manifest. Assigned users and roles in the client only. Now when I created the same set of roles in API app's manifest and assigned those roles in Users list of the API, I can see the roles in the access token. Thanks for your help.

Comment: is there a way to simplify the process of adding the same users / groups for both apps? I mean it can be tedious to maintain the same information in 2 places.

Comment: If the users in question have Azure AD Premium P2 licenses, you could use Entitlement Management access packages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/entitlement-management-overview

Comment: Although the solution would work, that doesn't sound like the right approach. If you want to limit the application to certain set of users, you would enable role assignment on the frontend/client app. But in this case, you have to perform certain actions on frontend/client app and certain on both. Assigning the users in two different apps is also quite tedious. Is this a limitation of Azure Entra ID?