# how to get roles in azure access token?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

in angular msal im able to get roles in id token by using this

```
 let accounts = this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts()[0];
  let roles = accounts.idTokenClaims?.roles;
console.log( roles)
```

but in access token when i decode it i dont get roles in the access token , and in my client app registration in app permission i gave it permission to my api app registered in azure
[image]

and in token configuration i added those settings
[image]

what i should do to get the roles in the access token

Comment: Have you checked this older answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64443475/1658906

Comment: yes i defined the same role in both api and client app

Comment: ah sorry i just checked the assigned group role in my api app and it had default access so i changed it to my custom role and now the roles is available in the access token, please post it as an answer