# Azure AD v2 - roles not included in Access Token

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, azure-entra-id

following the same issue already asked in stack overflow( [Azure AD v2 roles not included in Access Token](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66348270)).
i have tried the solution but it is not working for me. ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/66348704 ).

Roles are not part of access token/ ID token
Frontend Client is built using Angular.
Backend using NodeJS.
followed the tutorial and cloned official github projects.

i have registered both applications and configured them correctly.
i am using external public accounts not organizational accounts, i invited a user from azure entra and made gave him admin role

Added Scopes for my node app
[image]

Added Role for my node app[image]

Assigned role to user
[image]

{
endpoint: `http://localhost:5000/api/
scopes: {
write: [ "api://[node-application-Id]/TimeSheetTemplate.ReadWrite" ]
}
},

Request URL:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
200 OK
Remote Address:
40.126.18.33:443
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Payload

client_id: [angular-application-Id]
scope: api://[node-application-Id]/TimeSheetTemplate.ReadWrite openid profile offline_access
grant_type:
refresh_token
client_info:
1
x-client-SKU:
msal.js.browser
x-client-VER:
3.7.1
x-ms-lib-capability:
retry-after, h429
x-client-current-telemetry:
5|61,0,,,|@azure/msal-angular,3.0.11
x-client-last-telemetry:
5|0|||0,0
client-request-id: [angular-application-Id]
refresh_token:
M.C105_BAY.-Cgu4NLSGJ8NnC8QMdz6Vv8ZHK0rLZZHkUQOvQJoeoYPxAxdIhn3oGpn6CNhwkTtFHI!7AXK0GabGzI7NmLXNUeL37zVwyWGUdQyAElqMK4nxSp8jVmr2ibLQUVHXdkDcrQJRYhCjSDE0QqpNhfJPmSUulFSMLG8FtaTKr5eEFFmPshJGLZI1wP7b78m0UMnzgA4o!89UhUnNiFuToC13ndifFa1z5n3XroZMXbinKIN!dv!uEKXWl6fDxTtgRKSeyG6wayLhcDOSMZP6YATq0StwiGVQCfitbsOKOd0ucYTNlBWiBTQaouk9fUQfITMwXh2h8qu8SRU7mRNo80oS8$
X-AnchorMailbox: Oid:00000000-0000-0000-d8db-351d7555e529@9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad

Response

{

"token_type": "Bearer", "scope": "api://[node-application-Id]/TimeSheetTemplate.ReadWrite api://[node-application-Id]/TimeSheetList.ReadWrite api://[node-application-Id]/TimeSheetList.Read", "expires_in": 3600, "ext_expires_in": 3600,
"access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjJTcG9oaDl5Mm1lNTJuS3JoYWk3R3hXSmliVSJ9.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.ez3vQ4d4M7D2J-AyYzMFZze3_DQn2_XuG31YB6TEvSqhUrT--cObM0D-xcjQsD5PXR78lzYTM1e6JjIaV1CdUPLHBei38gaQFwLG9xJ9uFK3lKpV3Ba9jDm8D8GU2uku20JWivC457Uuo1f0UfXavKknVUnA3yy7hPr_iKhqAk2Fg9w20-CCDvWVM0fX9yPnfOlJYnhwm4g5uyOifnPUXy4ifxX38z68IgBrJxW3FQw7PXkorWQJOsgm9Cd65GhJJWQhkMTT0uvfaQEiiBAZ_ftLWheqb9ThG-jE-KnBfUzIjKJX4GK8KeOFe8CvKhx0F_RVa1CX5OKz7Csa2UESnw",

"refresh_token": "M.C105_BAY.-CpkCvUofwIkM8zmuBL42sAjbAWHHVUoqhz2qCiiLbkqR!al0jWy9JUEpiLi8Jl2GYqYeNHfME6upOKjAHiHJM1lnubg5GjSVqzAj51RPfpG9Da0cYqVhvmRhqyi07JErjhWvMAbrzPtVJ4am91J0NE1rhY55WAxx1QnLk8ug5tG6ETAzWlV9RSW4OJ4vHVMsGZ**1yq1y7wMR6Xja6mqGERwkJlpoYSccuielViJeYYz5FFJ1YcfaUrkvl0Ahv722h7NxShRQWrgvibtY9c6tHRL0y4GGaEKdy4ElAJpvGtfMaGMQ!z89A!c0!mqtGZRtvIJeMdJNsQmfo0DBFfYmXc4iIU95M1Nlz8zVXZGz8E9TrXiR4NTZZLlQ8p0xZdWHe*ODZku2Rh0HpDRvmeAHU!FbUeAO!SDFDojVc", "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjJTcG9oaDl5Mm1lNTJuS3JoYWk3R3hXSmliVSJ9.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.XGzplVHMJL2xyNKSRJnkcA4QLiDtth-Wc7MzLIpLMLPUohmLIOY-_2Y3Kujq3r6k6uhn2CoEi3I_4F3ENyyWb4VihsSdETMwstc8_bc7EygHLcG9nS_o0cb-D9W-6L0D_dpPR0ZbhWzvH6Z_Ek762xGdiG7lNwTje-EQdiwtZODDhyMPhTavIZz5shcjLwa0ctBjuqgZamzVnZqYcDzbnQHMzaeVuhQe10cGLKGCRLmKq3ZeZDmHzfSfqM_cocwyTDd7mrxmhliP-nUJ5qhMVFoY9hunYlhSDXyCUMFlnQijgftr_AzPCx1eRPzaLHX5yfo9miJwl-MT68Edx2F5CA", "client_info": "eyJ2ZXIiOiIxLjAiLCJzdWIiOiJBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFCbEFoR04tNkNqbDE5N3luTWg0d3NzIiwibmFtZSI6IkFiZHVsIEtoYWRlciIsInByZWZlcnJlZF91c2VybmFtZSI6ImFiZHVsa2hhZGVyNDEyM0BvdXRsb29rLmNvbSIsIm9pZCI6IjAwMDAwMDAwLTAwMDAtMDAwMC1kOGRiLTM1MWQ3NTU1ZTUyOSIsInRpZCI6IjkxODgwNDBkLTZjNjctNGM1Yi1iMTEyLTM2YTMwNGI2NmRhZCIsImhvbWVfb2lkIjoiMDAwMDAwMDAtMDAwMC0wMDAwLWQ4ZGItMzUxZDc1NTVlNTI5IiwidWlkIjoiMDAwMDAwMDAtMDAwMC0wMDAwLWQ4ZGItMzUxZDc1NTVlNTI5IiwidXRpZCI6IjkxODgwNDBkLTZjNjctNGM1Yi1iMTEyLTM2YTMwNGI2NmRhZCJ9" }

i added roles to a user and expected it to be part of access or id token

Comment: In the 3rd screenshot, we can see the display name you marked is `adbul-admin` but we can't see it within the first and the second screenshot, here's what I concerned. And I trust you `forgot to add api permission` in the app you exposed API. what Carl said `Next, go to the client application, give your client application access to your backend api:Under 'API permissions' click on 'Add permission', then click on the 'My APIs' tab.`

Comment: application roles we exposed is used for [role based access control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/role-based-access-control/custom-overview) for web app, I'm not sure why you need to have roles and scp claim in the same access token. By the way, the roles in access token and roles in id token is different.

Comment: and this answer might be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64443475/14574199

Answer (score 0):

I created a test app role:

[image]

And Exposed and API and added scope like below:

[image]

Now In Enterprise application I assigned the app role to the user:

[image]

Make sure to grant admin consent to the roles and scope:

[image]

Generated auth-code:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://ID/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

Generated tokens like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID  
scope:api://ID/.default openid offline_access
grant_type:authorization_code  
code:code  
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:Secret
```

[image]

**When I decoded the access token roles and scp is present:**

[image]

In ID token roles claim is present:

[image]

Make sure to add the API permission in the client application.

Refer this [**SO Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64443441/how-to-add-roles-claim-in-access-token-currently-it-is-coming-in-id-token/64443475#64443475) by junnas, which states that if you are making use of separate app registrations for the client and API, you should define the role in both apps and assign the user to it on both of them as well.